# Torsion elements and subgroups of nonabelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

I am currently studying torsion groups and I am playing around with defintions to get used to them.
An element $g \in G$ is a torsion element, if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $g^n = e$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of the group.

I was looking at a group $G$ and its set of torsion elements $G_t$. For a non-abelian group, I was able find an example where the set of torsion elements is no subgroup of the abelian group.

Now I am trying to find examples the other way round. Assume $G$ is nonabelian and I want the torsion elements set to be a (proper) subgroup of $G$.
All I could come up with were trivial subgroups like the quaternions. Do you have any examples where the torsion elements form a nontrivial subgroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of torsion elements of an abelian group is certainly a subgroup.

For the example you're looking for in non abelian groups, consider a free group $F$ on two elements, which has no nontrivial torsion elements; then consider any finite nontrivial group $G$; then $F\times G$ will give you the example.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had a look at the permutation group of $\mathbb{Z}$, so that was clearly non-abelian.

Comment: I think an even easier examples is $\mathbb{Z} \times S_3$. This is nonabelian and all elements of a finite group are in the torsion set. in the integers, only $0$ is in there, so this works out as well.

Comment: @max Too easy! `;-)` Yes, it's as good.